# Can an uncountable collection of sets be turned into a collection of disjoint sets?

Tags: set-theory

Let $S$ be an uncountable collection of sets. Is it possible to make the sets in $S$ pairwise disjoint by removing the intersections? Specifically, can we build the set $\hat{S}$ from $S$ by doing the following:
For all pairs $s_1, s_2 \in S$, remove the intersection $s_1 \cap s_2$ from $s_1$. Can I claim that the sets in $\hat{S}$ are pariwise disjoint and that the union of $\hat{S}$ is equal to the union of $S$?

Thanks

Comment: There's a way to do this, but the pairwise-disjoint collection might not be uncountable.  To take an easy example, let your uncountable collection of subsets be $\mathscr P(\Bbb N)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S= \{S_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \lt \kappa \}$ where $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal.

Define $T_\alpha = S_\alpha \setminus \bigcup_{\xi \lt \alpha} S_\xi.$  Then the non-empty $T_\alpha$ are pairwise disjoint and $\bigcup S_\alpha= \bigcup T_\alpha$.

Comment: Is this possible for any uncountable set S or is there some required condition?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!